# If we Disable TLS 1.0,TLS 1.1 and Enable only TLS 1.2 Support in SharePoint 2013 Servers?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security

Hi according to our security policies if we disable TLS 1.0,1.1 and enable only TLS 1.2 in SharePoint servers is there any impact to SharePoint Farm and its Services.
TLS 1.2 will support in SharePoint Servers?

SharePoint Version we have **2013** & **Windows Server 2012**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, TLS 1.2 is supported in SharePoint 2013, Windows 2012, and SQL 2012. However, when only TLS 1.2 is enabled, need to make sure that it's enabled on all the SharePoint Servers in the Farm and also on the client (browser) assessing SharePoint sites.

For more information, refer to MS Article [Enable TLS and SSL support in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Hi i did not found any clear steps to enable TLS 1.2 for SP 2013, steps mentioned in above links is not clear, i was stuck in some steps like 1.2 - Enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 support in WinHTTP, 1.4 - Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client update for TLS 1.2 support

Comment: Please check sections 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7 that talk about SharePoint 2013, which is built on .NET Framework

Comment: Hi enabled tls 1.2 and disable  SSL3.0,TLS 1.1 & 1.2 and SharPoint is working fine but using ODBC driver SQL Server is not connecting  in the event viewer there are many errors for SCHANNEL : A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.

Comment: You need to identify which application or process is failing to connect SQL server using ODBC and then target that. Oftentimes, we see many errors in the event viewer log, but those might not be an actual issues.